# open a workbook from network drive and paste the data in existing workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbook. WB1, is my active workbook from network folder itself, and WB2 is the workbook that is already available in the network drive.

I wanted to open WB2, copy all the contents and paste In WB1 and close WB2 without saving.

Additionally, I am trying to delete in column 8 of WB1 all those that does not contain "TRU".

I tried the below code , But I am not sure how I could specify the get to open for my Network drive.

here is my code.

```
Sub newWB()
Dim WB1 As workbook
Dim WB2 As workbook
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim totalrows As Long
Dim PasteToStart As Range
Dim FileToOpen
Dim sheet As Worksheet

Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set PasteToStart = [Sheet1!A1]

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("file://cw.wan.com/root/Loc/PL/04/Projektlist.xlsx")

If FileToOpen = False Then
MsgBox ("no File Found")
Exit Sub

Else

Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)

For Each sheet In WB2.Sheets

With sheet.UsedRange
.Copy PasteToStart
Set PasteToStart = PasteToStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
End With
Next sheet
End If

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    totalrows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = totalrows To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, 8).Value <> "TRU" Then
        Cells(i, 8).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
Next
End With

WB2.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: windows network drives are mapped like \\remotemachine\locationname. Check your actual map path in cmd with `net use`. The file path that you provide in GetOpenFileName is plain garbage. remove that.

Comment: Or you could open a file dialog and let the user choose the location. Unless it never changes I suppose.

Comment: @cyboashu    the problem is , I could see its mapped in "T", but its not me who is going to use the file. I have other colleagues as well  who use them from other machines.. so how do I then do it

Comment: @JacobH the user wants it to do it automatically. He doesn't want file dialog option. I tried it already.

Comment: Reread @cyboashu comment. Or google "fully qualified domain name" vs "UNC path" vs "mapped drive".

Comment: Is it possible I could define them in a path ??? could any one help with the code ?

Comment: Dude we can't see your network how can we give you the server path??????????? Think about this. *YOU* need to do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164415/discussion-between-mikz-and-jacob-h).

Comment: When you go to Computer and look at your T drive it says something like `FolderName (\\SERVERNAME) (T:)` you need `\\SERVERNAME\FOLDERNAME`